# How to simulate IMU data using position and orientation?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, integration, simulation

I want to make a simulator to verify that my imu algorithm is working.

I am given:

$p_0$ - starting position

$p_1$ - final position

$q_0$ - starting orientation

$q_1$ - final orientation

I want to start from $(p_0, q_0)$ and move to $(p_1, q_1)$ using imu information $(gx, gy, gz, ax, ay, az)$. How can I convert the data I have into gyroscope $(gx, gy, gz)$ and accelerometer $(ax, ay, az)$ data of an imu.

Comment: What is the data you have?

Comment: @Arkamis I have p0, p1, q0, and q1 data as stated above.

Comment: So you have the start points and end points and no data whatsoever about the path?

Comment: @Arkamis it's linear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use a 4x4 affine matrix that represent all the transformation on the sensor. After apply each transformation we get the position and orientation and thus get angular velocity and acceleration that an IMU would give out.